# Drop-down list disappears when workbook is emailed

Tags: excel, email, validation

I have a drop-down list on an Excel 2010 workbook created by using the Data Validation tool.  The list's data is a range on a separate sheet in the same workbook.

However, when I email this workbook to someone else and they open it, the drop-down list disappears.  This doesn't affect any of my other cells with data validation types other than "List".

Is there a Trust Center setting I'm missing here, or is this a known issue with Excel?

Comment: What version of Excel is the recipient using?

Comment: I'll know when I connect into their computer later.  I suspected this could be the issue, was just wondering if there were any other known culprits.

Comment: I recommend double checking the validation to make sure it's connecting to the same workbook.